# SQL Server 2008: Get date part from datetime2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime2

I've been using this very handy method of extracting the date portion from a `datetime` value:

```
select dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, @inDate), 0)
```

This basically zeroes out the time portion of the date. It's fast, and more importantly it's deterministic - you can use this expression in a persisted computed column, indexed view, etc.

However I'm struggling to come up with something that works with the `datetime2` type. The problem being that SQL Server does not permission conversions from integers to the `datetime2` type.

Is there an equivalent, **deterministic** method of stripping the time portion from a `datetime2`?

Comment: How about `SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @inDate)`? Or `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2, CONVERT(DATE, @inDate))` if you need to return a `DATETIME2`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can't you just do a

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD DateOnly AS CAST(YourDate AS DATE) PERSISTED
```

The `CAST(... AS DATE)` turns your datetime2 column into a "date-only", and it seems to be deterministic enough to be used in a persisted, computed column definition ...

Comment: I guess so! cast with datetime is not deterministic, but apparently it's okay to be used with date and datetime2...